# Playground of Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, editor

editor of typescriptlang.org[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html] is premium. but I cannot find which editor used in bellow page.

can you prefer good typescript editor like it?

Comment: The editor used in the TypeScriptLang.org playground is Ace (https://ace.c9.io/)

Comment: @EduardDumitru: That's incorrect, Ace is also a great editor but TypeScript Playground uses Monaco.

Comment: Its monaco. Other IDEs using it include vscode and my own http://alm.tools/

Comment: You’re completely right @basarat I dunno why I believed it to be Ace. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editor used in the TypeScript Playground is [Monaco](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor). It uses the same editor that powers [VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode). On the GitHub page you can find [instructions and code samples](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html) to embed it in your website if you'd like.